# How can i apply the proper image to the ImageView based on the application Locale?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

Is there any way to have different images for different languages for an ImageView?

Imagine i have this two picture, first one is for a right to left language and second one is for an left to right language, how can i apply the proper image to the ImageView based on my application Locale?

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/message_icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/message_text_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/message_text_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/sent_message_icon"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></ImageView>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place normal image in the `drawable-*` folder rtl image in the `drawable-ldrtl-*` folder.

If you want to use single image:

Place `<integer name="angle_rtl_180">0</integer>` in `values/integers`

and

`<integer name="angle_rtl_180">180</integer>` in `values-ldrtl/integers`

then use `rotationY` attribute in the imageView as:

```
android:rotationY="@integer/angle_rtl_180"
```

Comment: is the * my locale? like drawable-ldrtl-fa?

Comment: the screen densities like drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, etc

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to create different images  as you mentioned the scenario because that will increase the size of the apk. You need to check if the language has changes there is method to rotate the view. You just rotate the around x and y axis pass the require rotation angle and you are done. you can use below code to rotate

```
imageView.setRotation(angle);
```

angle is the value you want to rotate
Hope this helps you